# Calculating css gradient difference

Tags: css, sass, less

Being a friend of symmetry I usually design everything I do that in mind.  Lately I've been using a lot of linear gradients to style my buttons.  As propably every developer I spend a lot of time with an online gradient generator choosing colors at random between two points and pretty much just "eye-ball it".

However what if I wanted more precision?  Lets say I have a gradient starting with #ff5db1 and ending with #ef017c.  What if I wanted to make sure that every other gradient I use in the future has the same kind of intensity and percentual difference between the two colors than previous two.

> Is there a tool that calculates the metrics between two colors so I
>   can create a kind of consistent color scheme based on those metrics?

Comment: See my comment at the answer below. And here's the [demo](http://codepen.io/seven-phases-max/pen/pJBXYP?editors=110) to illustrate that: 1. any arithmetic metrics generally is quite limited. 2. If you still decide to use it - you won't need any external tool since this can be fully automated within a preprocessor.

Answer (score -1):

Basically, I think you can. For example take your colors - #ef017c and #ff5db1. So, every 2 numbers or letter, it's one color in HEX. For example, in #ff5db1 ff - red, 5d - green, b1 - blue. You can calculate how many it's in DEC.

For #ff5db1:
(ff)16 = (255)10,
(5d)16 = (93)10,
(b1)16 = (177)10.

ff5db1 = (255, 93, 177)

For #ef017c:
(ef)16 = (239)10,
(01)16 = (1)10,
(7c)16 = (124)10

ef017c = (239, 1, 124).

Then you calculate the difference between them.

ff5db1 - ef017c = ((255 - 239), (93 - 1), (177 - 124)) = (16, 92, 53) - this is the deference between two colors.

Comment: Well, it is quite trivial to calculate arithmetic difference between RGB values of colors (or better between their HSL/HSB) - but neither gives really valuable information for the *perceptual* difference between two colors. (Even [Luminance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luminance)/[Luma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luma_(video)) that are supposed to represent perceptual difference between lightness/brightness of two colors has quite limited use). In other words, HSL difference would work to a certain degree but it never can reach perceptual consistency of a manually designed color scheme.